# How to prove that $T$ is a normal operator

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional inner product space $V$. Let $E_i(i=1,2,\cdots,r)$ be linear operators on V such that $T=\lambda_1E_1+\cdots+\lambda_rE_r$ and $E_iE_j=\vec{0}$ for $i\neq j$. Then prove that $T$ is normal.

**My approach**:
$T=\lambda_1E_1+\cdots+\lambda_rE_r$ give a intuition that $T$ canbe written as a diagonal matrix such that $$T=P^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0&\cdots\\0&\lambda_2&\cdots\\ \vdots&\cdots&\lambda_r\end{pmatrix}P$$

> I know that if $T$ is normal then it can be represented by a diagonal matrix relative to an orthonormal basis.

seems $E_iE_j=0$ for $i\neq j$ then $E_i$ provide this orthogonal basis. Last I need to show that this is an orthonormal too that's mean $P^{-1}=P^T$. Where I stuck. Eventually I am not sure is my approach is correct or not. 
Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you assuming each $E_i$ is normal?

Comment: As I understand $E_i$ should be normal but I can't deduce that @LordSharktheUnknown from given statement in the question

Comment: Is $E_iE_j = \delta_{ij}I$?

Comment: @Azif00 maybe because it only says about $E_iE_j=0$ when $i\neq j$. Let guessing it's $E_iE_i=I$ then how to prove that

Comment: The problem is that unless you're given some further information about $\ E_i\ $, the result you're supposed to prove is not necessarily true.  Take $\ r=1\ $, $\ \lambda_1=1\ $ and $\ E_1\ $ to be any non-normal operator, for instance. Then $\ T=E_1\ $ is not normal.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera the question didn't mention any information of $E_i$. But I am assuming that $(E_i)^2=E_i$ make $T$ a normal operator by spectral theorem.

Comment: If the $E_i$ satisfy $E_i^2 = E_i$, then we would also need to know that $E_i$ is self-adjoint in order to guarantee that $T$ is normal.  For instance, $r = 1, \lambda_1 = 1$, and 
$$
E_1 = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}
$$
leads to a non-normal operator.